# Powershell progress bar vertical space

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I added 4 write-progress bars in a powershell script, each used by a different job running. It's working great, except that when I get 3 or more going, they run out of vertical space and start leaving out the actual progress bar. Not only that, but as they are written to (separately and asynchronously), they shift around as some add the progress bar back, and others remove it to get smaller. They also change the arrangement of the fields to take up more or less lines. They jump around enough that it's hard to read the numbers.

I can fix this by making the window height a size such that all of the progress bars are displaying in the same format. When there is enough space for 1 or more to be a larger format, that's when the jumping happens. It seems that the problem is that when there are multiple formats being displayed, it doesn't always distribute the formats consistently to the same bars. Is there anything I can do to change the vertical space allocated or to lock them into a single display format so they are readable?

Here are two screenshots within a minute of each other:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**:

I was able to reproduce it on the system powershell console, so I don't think it is ConEmu related.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to ConEmu and can not be reproduced with RAW conhost. Your screenshots are cropped and that's why not reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Maximus. I tried again and was able to reproduce it with the system powershell console, so I think you're right. Regardless, I've updated my screenshots to include the whole window.

Comment: Now that I'm reading the docs, I'm able to see it on the "RealConsole" as well, so not ConEmu.

Comment: A few years old now, but a detailed explanation of the progress bar behavior at the time: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1016#issue-201171835

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know how to change the default progress bar, but there is a module called `PoshProgressBar` situated under this [link](http://tiberriver256.github.io/PoshProgressBar/).

Example: `New-ProgressBar -MaterialDesign -IsIndeterminate $False -Type Vertical -Size Medium -Theme Dark`

The progress bar is shown in a seperate window.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to adjust your buffer size and your windowsize so you have room for the whole progressbar control

in example:

```
$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui

$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
$newsize.height = 8000
$newsize.width = 120
$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize

$newsize = $pswindow.windowsize
#$newsize.height = 40
#$newsize.width = 120
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I realized that it only happens when using ConEmu, so I'm updating the question accordingly.

Comment: Was able to reproduce without ConEmu

Comment: Thanks, I dug into this a little further, and it is based on height, but I only seem to be able to set it to 50 max. Also, it would be better to be able to change the format settings than to set the window height to be bigger than my screen. :)

Comment: If you change the width you need to change the buffersize width als.